# How do I reverse transversal in a PowerShell array

Tags: powershell, reverse, traversal

Given a PowerShell <s>array</s> hashtable<sup>1</sup>  similar to the following:

```
$dept= @{
     'Sales' = @{
        'SAM' = 'Manager'
        'SAP' = 'Person'
    }
    'IT' = @{
        'ITM' = 'Manager'
        'ITS' = 'Specialist'
        'ITT' = 'Technician'
        'ITC' = 'Consultant'     
    }
}
```

If enter the following in the console:

```
$dept.it.itc
$dept.sales.sam
```

I get:

```
Consultant
Manager
```

Which is as expected.

However, what I'd like to do is something like

```
write-host $dept.itc
write-host $dept.sam
```

and get

```
IT Consultant
Sales Manager
```

in return.

I'm looking for a sort function to do a 'reverse traversal' of the array because 'IT', 'Sales' etc are the OU's I need to put new users into. There are many more OU's that I have removed for brevity.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> An *array* is simply a list of values and a *hashtable* is a collection of key/value pairs similiar to Javascript's JSON or Python's `dict`.

Comment: As an aside: I suggest not using `Write-Host` in sample code, as it might mislead beginners to think that (a) using a cmdlet is necessary to produce output in PowerShell (it isn't) and that (b) the cmdlet to use for producing output is `Write-Host` (it generally isn't, unless your intent is to _write directly to the screen_ (host) rather than to _output data_).

Comment: just FYI - your object is NOT an array. [*grin*] this >>> `@{}` creates a hashtable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is worth noting that your object is not an `Array`. In PowerShell `@{}` is a `Hashtable`. You can read more about working with Hashtables [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.2).

If you have what I am going to call a unique **Role Code** for each role in your department OU's, all you want to do is match the `Key` in the nested Hashtables to find your department. It's easiest to create a quick helper function to deal with multiple calls, unless you are just looping through an array or list of strings.

Here is an example of how to extract the string you want: (If you do not have unique keys, then you may need to add additional filtering)

```
$Departments = @{
    'Sales' = @{
        'SAM' = 'Manager'
        'SAP' = 'Person'
    }
    'IT'    = @{
        'ITM' = 'Manager'
        'ITS' = 'Specialist'
        'ITT' = 'Technician'
        'ITC' = 'Consultant'     
    }
}

function Get-DepartmentOU {
    Param (
        [CmdletBinding()]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.String]
        $RoleCode
    )

    # Get the DictionaryEntry in the main Hashtable where the nested Hashtable value matches the role you are looking for.
    $Department = $script:Departments.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.Value.ContainsKey($RoleCode) }
    
    # Print the name of the DictionaryEntry (Your department) and retrieve the value from the Hashtable for the role.
    Write-Output ("{0} {1}" -f $Department.Name, $Department.Value[$RoleCode])
}
```

And then you can get them by running the function and specifying the code.

```
PS > Get-DepartmentOU -RoleCode ITC
IT Consultant
```