# How to reverse traverse a nested hashtable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, hashtable, reverse, enumerate

In a previous question, I was given [a solution for finding the name of a key by its value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71888502/how-do-i-reverse-transversal-in-a-powershell-array). Unfortunately I neglected to consider the application of Security Groups

**Old hashtable and working function**

```
$Departments = @{
    'Sales' = @{
        'SAM' = 'Manager'
        'SAP' = 'Person'
    }
    'IT'    = @{
        'ITM' = 'Manager'
        'ITS' = 'Specialist'
        'ITT' = 'Technician'
        'ITC' = 'Consultant'     
    }
}

function Get-DepartmentOU {
    Param (
        [CmdletBinding()]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.String]
        $RoleCode
    )

    # Get the DictionaryEntry in the main Hashtable where the nested Hashtable value matches the role you are looking for.
    $Department = $script:Departments.GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { $_.Value.ContainsKey($RoleCode) }

    # Print the name of the DictionaryEntry (Your department) and retrieve the value from the Hashtable for the role.
    "Department: $($Department.Name) Job Title: $($Department.Value[$RoleCode])" 

}


$JobCode = "SAM"
$DepartmentInfo = Get-DepartmentOU -RoleCode $JobCode
$DepartmentInfo
```

**OUTPUT**:   `Department: Sales Job Title: Manager`

The above works excellently, however I've now created a deeper hashtable and need to do the same thing, just another level to extract more information.

**New hashtable**

```
$Departments = @{
    "Parts" = @{
        "SG-Parts" = @{
            "PAM" = "Parts Manager"
            "PAA" = "Parts Advisor"
        }
    }
    "Sales" = @{
        "SG-Sales"          = @{
            "SAP" = "Sales Person"
            "SAR" = "Receptionist"
        }
        "SG-Sales Managers" = @{
            "SGM" = "General Manager"
            "SAM" = "Sales Manager"
        }

    }
}
```

How should I change the working function to display the text contained in the key

**OUTPUT**:   `SG: SG-Sales Managers Department: Sales Job Title: Manager`

---

This may help to visualize the data structure that @mathias-r.-jessen's 'flat role table/map' code generates:

```
$Rolemap = @{
    "PAC" = @{
        "Title"      = "Parts Consultant"
        "SG"         = "SG-Parts"
        "Department" = "Parts"
    }
    "PAA" = @{
        "Title"      = "Parts Advisor"
        "SG"         = "SG-Parts"
        "Department" = "Parts"
    }
    "SGM" = @{
        "Title"      = "General Manager"
        "SG"         = "SG-Sales Managers"
        "Department" = "Sales"
    }
}
```

The original data structure is quicker for humans to modify as needed as it mimics a common small-scale Active Directory setup.

When using the original data format, each new role addition only has to be added to the correct 'group' within the hashtable. However, reversing the `"SAM" = "Sales Manager"` to `"Sales Manager"="SAM"` may help for legibility and logic / structure.

I used `$RoleMap |Format-Custom` and some manual typing to build the generated table visualization text.

Comment: In my opinion, this defeats the purpose of a hashtable, if you're relying on `.GetEnumerator()` to get your results, mind as well be a nested array a `pscustomobjects`

Comment: `GetEnumerator()` + `Where-Object` is quite the antipattern. Sure you don't want to organize your hashtable differently?

Comment: Whether the data is in arrays, hashtables, dicts, JSON, XML, SQL or something else doesn't seem all that important as long as I can get the information I'm looking for. I can re-write the data in whatever format is easier to use.

Comment: What Mathias shows in his answer (the construction of `$RoleMap = @{}`) is how you should have your data structure to begin with

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon OP's current data structure saves some source code repetition compared to storing the flat map produced by my answer :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I partially agree but also, maybe the data structure should not be harcoded in the script itself and have it as json / xml as OP already implied in previous comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new flat role table from your OU-like hashtable structure:

```
$RoleMap = @{}

foreach($departmentCode in $Departments.psbase.Keys){
    foreach($sgCode in $Departments[$departmentCode].psbase.Keys){
        foreach($roleCode in $Departments[$departmentCode][$sgCode].psbase.Keys){
            # Create a summary object that includes all 3 pieces of information
            # Store in role table and use the "role code" as the key
            $RoleMap[$roleCode] = [pscustomobject]@{
                Title = $Departments[$departmentCode][$sgCode][$roleCode]
                SG = $sgCode
                Department = $departmentCode
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can avoid `...GetEnumerator() | Where-Object { ... }` completely when resolving the role code:

```
function Get-DepartmentOU {
    param(
        [CmdletBinding()]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]
        $RoleCode
    )

    if($script:RoleMap.Contains($RoleCode)){
        # `Where-Object` no longer needed!
        $roleDescription = $script:RoleMap[$RoleCode]

        "SG: $($roleDescription.SG) Department: $($roleDescription.Name) Job Title: $($roleDescription.Title)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Would you be able to demonstrate what the ```$RoleMap``` structure would look like or how I can get powershell to print the structure? I don't need to use hashtables for any other reason other than similar code I looked at used hashtables.

Comment: @ill13 Does `$RoleMap |Format-Custom` show you what you want to see?

Comment: I did change ```$($roleDescription.Name)``` to ```$($roleDescription.Department)```